# Archiving DB with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, database-design

I have a website which data will be changed every year, so I want to archive the DB and retrieve it according to the year. But I'm confused and don't know the best practice from these cases:

1. creating another DB for the new year and change connections when applicable.
2. copying only the tables that will be changed at the same database with different names, then change table name in the model when accessing the DB.
3. Copying all rows and inserting them again into the according tables with a year column to differentiate between each year.

Which approach is the best one according to DB and the whole application performance?

Comment: You want yearly backup in sql/zip file? 
Need old year data in DB after New Year Eve? 
You should provide more as db architecture (with some example rows) and model code you are using now.